# Proof by contradiction: Let A and B be sets. Prove that (A\B) ∩ (B\A) = ∅.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here's what I have so far. I feel that I am close but missing the final link of showing that the set is empty...maybe I'm just not sure how to word it.

Proof.
Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Suppose $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $(A \setminus B)\cap(B \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$. 
Then $x \in (A \setminus B)$ and $y \in (B \setminus A)$, but $x \notin (B \setminus A)$ and $y \notin (A \setminus B)$.
*Right here is where I'm having trouble. Was the above sentence worth it?*

At this point I realized that I'm only specifically speaking about single elements of $A$ and $B$, and may want to instead include $\forall$.

Can anyone get me on the right track?

Comment: Since their intersection is nonempty, there exists an $x$ which is in both sets. Why is this a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because x can't be in both A minus B and B minus A by definition of set minus.

Comment: Exactly! Thats the contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, $x\in A$ and $(A\backslash B)\cap(B\backslash A)\neq\varnothing$ together doesn't imply $x\in A\backslash B$.

Here's what you want: Suppose $(A\backslash B)\cap(B\backslash A)\neq\varnothing$. Then there exists $x\in(A\backslash B)\cap(B\backslash A)$. Therefore $x\in A\backslash B$, so $x\notin B$. However, we also get $x\in B\backslash A$, meaning $x\in B$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: In this case, is there also the contradiction that from $x \in B\setminus A, x \notin A$?

Edit: I am confident that this is true.

Comment: @dewick49 yes that's true as well

Comment: Great! That makes a lot of sense then. That proof was actually quite enjoyable. Pardon the off-topic comment, but I've found that proof by contradiction is much more fun than my previous proof templates.

Comment: @dewick49 yeah they make you feel clever once it's like "yes I got a contradiction!" lol